# How to use reserved words in FSharp.Data.XmlProvider?

Tags: xml, f#, type-providers, f#-data, fsharp.data.typeproviders

I am using `FSharp.Data.XmlProvider`.  My xml contains a `<load>` node.  The type provider already has a static `Load` member used to load an instance.  I looked for documentation regarding how to have the XmlProvider properly interpret reserved words but have not found anything.  Can someone provide insight on how to generate my `<load>` node in the type provider?  Perhaps a constructor parameter that can tell `XmlProvider` that I have reserved words as nodes in my xml?

Code sample:

```
module LoadModule =
  [<Literal>]
  let loadSample = """
    <root>
      <loads>
        <load loadid="1" value="12345" />
      </loads>
    </root>"""
  type LoadXml = XmlProvider<loadSample>
  let loadXml = LoadXml.Load("")  // This is the static member Load.  LoadXml does not contain a `Load` member for my node
  let x = loadXml.Load // The instance does contain my Load member, 
                       // but I need to construct a `Load []` using a static `Load` member 
                       // because I need to set the values programmatically.  
                       // Instance members are not settable.
```

Answer (score 3):

You use the `new` keyword to resolve to the correct overload:

```
[<Literal>]
let loadSample = """
  <root>
    <loads>
      <load loadid="1" value="12345" />
    </loads>
  </root>"""
type LoadXml = XmlProvider<loadSample>
let loadXml = LoadXml.Parse("...")
let x = LoadXml.Root (new LoadXml.Load(loadid=1,value=12345) )
```

Also note that indicating in the sample that `loads` can contain multiple `load`-items, the `LoadXml.Root` constructor takes an array of `Load` instances instead of a single instance:

```
[<Literal>]
let loadSample = """
  <root>
    <loads>
      <load loadid="1" value="12345" />
      <load loadid="2" value="23456" />
    </loads>
  </root>"""
type LoadXml = XmlProvider<loadSample>
let loadXml = LoadXml.Parse("...")
let x = LoadXml.Root [| new LoadXml.Load(loadid=1,value=12345); ... |]
```

Comment: Thanks! I was able to get the answer I needed from your post.  However, it wasn't adding extra rows, but simply using the `new` keyword in front of the `LoadXml.Load` constructor.  If you can change your answer to reflect this, I'll credit you with the answer.

Comment: @AaronPalmer The reason the `new` keyword makes all the difference is that it clarifies to the compiler that you want to invoke the constructor on the provided `Load` type, not invoke the static `Load` method that always exists on the type provider.  When you use the syntax in your original question, without the `new` keyword, the compiler thinks you're trying to invoke the static method instead of create an instance of the type.